# Outputting public properties on object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3 and I have to make a couple calls to a service layer and display the object properties.

Is it possible to use the .NET framework to output all the properties and collections in an object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reflection might be what might help you with that.